# Vim Javascript configure indent width on newline ending with parentheses

Tags: javascript, vim

### Problem:

For javascript filetype, my Vimrc autoindent 4 spaces on new line ending with `(`, but autoindent 2 spaces ending with `{`.

How to fix the autoindent to 2 spaces on newline ending with `(`?

### current [`.vimrc`](https://github.com/9gix/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc#L10)

```
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd Filetype javascript setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, javascript uses `cindent` with `cinoptions=j1,J1` for indenting.
See `$(VIMRUNTIME)/indent/javascript.vim`

As I am unable to deduce your requirement from the post clearly, I am assuming that what you want is something like this

```
function test(
  abc,
  efg
```

if so, you should be able to achieve it using

```
" you can add this in your autocmd
set cinoptions+=(0,W1s
```

if not, you might like to `:h cinoptions-values` for possible values for your requirement.